# Graph updating algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have a (un-directed) graph represented using adjacency lists, e.g.

```
a: b, c, e
b: a, d
c: a, d
d: b, c
e: a
```

where each node of the graph is linked to a list of other node(s)

I want to update such a graph given some new list(s) for certain node(s), e.g.

```
a: b, c, d
```

where `a` is no longer connected to `e`, and is connected to a new node `d`

What would be an efficient (both time and space wise) algorithm for performing such updates to the graph?

Comment: If you plan to add and remove edges a lot, then you'll probably want to use adjacency sets instead of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't it be fastest to use a dictionary (or default dict) of node-labels (strings or numbers) to sets? In this case update could look something like this:

```
def update(graph, node, edges, undirected=True):
    # graph: dict(str->set(str)), node: str, edges: set(str), undirected: bool
    if undirected:
        for e in graph[node]:
            graph[e].remove(node)
        for e in edges:
            graph[e].add(node)
    graph[node] = edges
```

Using sets and dicts, adding and removing the node to/from the edges-sets of the other nodes should be O(1), same as updating the edges-set for the node itself, so this should be only O(2n) for the two loops, with n being the average number of edges of a node.

Comment: I think this answer is the best. I had initially thought it would be beneficial to take the difference between the old and new set (in both directions) to find the subsets of removed and added edges, but after giving it a little more though I don't think that would actually improve performance at all (and it might even be worse, though still O(n)).

Answer (score 0):

Using an adjacency grid would make it O(n) to update, but would take n^2 space, regardless of how sparse the graph is.  (Trivially done by updating each changed relationship by inverting the row and column.)

Using lists would put the time up to O(n^2) for updating, but for sparse graphs would not take a huge time penalty, and would save a lot of space.

Comment: I'm not good with data structures, but shouldn't an adjacency list only take O(2n) space? Each edge only appears twice overall.

Comment: Number of possible edges is n^2, where you have n nodes.

Comment: alternatively use an actual sparse matrix class which have O(n+2*nnz) storage, where nnz=number of edges. Plenty of Python implementations available, including scipy's.

Comment: @bdares, thanks for the suggestions. isn't the adjacency grid thing you're proposing the same as an adjacency matrix?

Answer (score 0):

A typical update is `del edge a,e; add edge a,d`, but your update looks like a new adjacency list for vertex `a`. So simply find the `a` adjacency list and replace it. That should be O(log n) time (assuming sorted array of adjacency lists, like in your description).

Comment: I don't know if that will suffice: won't the OP have to update the adjacency lists for `d` and `e` as well?

Comment: @DSM, exactly, even though the provided list(s) may only be for a subset of nodes available, but the changes may affect beyond this subset of nodes.